# How to log class name in Xcode debugger

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

I have an object that is of a type `id`. This object can be one of my custom classes instance. Is there a way I can log its class name?

I tried casting it to `NSObject` but I got an error.

```
error: C-style cast from 'id' to 'NSObject' is not allowed
```

Here full output of the console:

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The class of an object is again an Objective-C *object*, so use `po` instead of `p`:

```
po [object class]
```

`po` is an abbreviation for `expression -o  --` and prints the *description* of the expression.

---

Your error is caused by the fact that `id` is a pointer and must be cast to
 `NSObject *`, not to `NSObject`. So this would work as well:

```
p [(NSObject *)object class]
```

Alternatively, cast the method's return type, as suggested by the lldb error message:

```
p (Class)[object class]
```

But `po` is the simplest solution for your problem.

Comment: Thanks. I realised I'm missing the `*` in the cast.

Answer (score 1):

You can type this in the command window to print to classname:

```
po NSStringFromClass([object class])
```

Comment: This will not work. `object` is not `self`. Typing `po NSStringFromClass([object class])` gives the same error.

Comment: This won't work, he is speaking about the debugger commands (log window below the Xcode editor), not objective-c methods.

Comment: But hey, of course this will work. (lldb) po NSStringFromClass([response class])
NSHTTPURLResponse

(lldb)

Comment: btw. did you know guys that you can execute _any_ code with the context of currently running process/function via expr?

Comment: @JurajAntas Yes, I do know that! :)

Answer (score 1):

None of these answers worked for me. So FWIW I do this:

- ObjC: `po variableName.class`
- Swift: `po type(of: variableName)`